# How to tell if an Excel cell has a formula or is hardcoded?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone have a special tip (non-VBA strongly preferred) to tell systematically if a cell has a hardcoded value or is a derived formula?

Am dealing with some data that has messy subtotals embedded in it and am trying to see if I can separate out the raw lines.

Comment: Does the "Show Formulas" mode (Ctrl + `) help?

Comment: It does, but I wouldn't consider it "systematic" - requires me to hand-blast away the subtotal lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Conditional formatting. Choose the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" option and type " =NOT(Cellhasformula) ". This will format anything that is hardcoded.

Comment: So this wasn't the full answer but it's actually quite elegant. The full answer is on: http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip045.htm

The key is that you 1st need to create a name (via Formulas -> Name Manager) called "Cellhasformula" that "refers to" the mystical formula 
    =GET.CELL(48,INDIRECT("rc",FALSE)).

As the link says, the formula uses GET.CELL, which is in the XLM macro language (VBA's predecessor) and can't be used directly in a worksheet. The "48" arg makes GET.CELL return 'True' if the cell has a formula. The INDIRECT basically creates a ref to each cell in the selected range.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include those details. Thanks @YGA

Answer (score 16):

Select the cells in question, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and then select `Special` to get the following dialog box:

[image: Go To Special dialog box]

Then specify the type of cells you want and click `OK` and only those types of cells will remain selected.

Answer (score 10):

As of Excel 2013, you can do:

```
=ISFORMULA(reference)
```

[Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/Article/ISFORMULA-function-e4d1355f-7121-4ef2-801e-3839bfd6b1e5) the complete documentation

Answer (score 3):

Two other methods are to

1. Use a mapping tool such as my [Mappit! addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2613-Mappit-a-free-Excel-model-auditing-addin.html)  (which can be run as a trusted addin)
2. You can use the very useful [XLM / Range Names workaround](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_7629-Using-XLM-with-Range-Names-and-Conditional-Formatting-to-automatically-format-spreadsheets-according-to-cell-content.html) which offers an real time colouring of hardcoded cells, formulae, linked cells etc. This doesn't require any programming knowledge to deploy unlike VBA

Comment: Repost the method#2 here please.  This will protect the solution in case the external link is dead

Answer (score 3):

```
=iferror(Formulatext(cell),"Not Formula")
```

or to show only the formulas:

```
=iferror(Formulatext(cell),"")
```

Comment: For anyone using LibreOffice Calc instead of Excel, replace formulatext() with formula().

Answer (score 1):

I know you said non-VBA preferred, but if you end up with no other solutions, the Range object has a HasFormula property.

Returns: True if all cells in the range contain formulas; False if none of the cells in the range contains a formula; null otherwise.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208626%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the Excel file in a macro-free workbook format, you should avoid both VBA and macros (i.e. the XL4/XLM approaches suggested in other answers). In this answer, I made the assumption of a macro-free Excel file.

If you use MS-Excel 2013, you can use:

```
=ISFORMULA(reference)
```

If you use older MS-Excel versions (e.g. 2010, 2007), there is no true function to determine if a cell contains a formula. However, you can approximate it using:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(reference);CELL("prefix";reference)<>"");FALSE;IF(CELL("type";reference)="l";TRUE;"MAYBE"))
```

The function above returns:

- TRUE for cells containing a formula wich results in a String data.
- FALSE for cells containing a String literal or is blank.
- "MAYBE" for cells containing a boolean, a number or a date, no matter if this value is literal or the result of a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Well past the original date, but if it's of use to anyone, I managed to get around this by selecting the range of cells, then using Replace (Ctrl+H), setting it to 'Look in' "Formulas" and replace an equals `=` with an apostrophe-equals `'=`

This brought out all the formulas, but obviously would also convert things like if $C$1 contained `=if($A1=$B1,"Match","Different")` to `'=if($A1'=$B1,"Match","Different")`

Notice the `A1'=B1` in the middle of the formula which may be problematic, but still means you get to see the formulas, albeit non-pragmatically. Could use the SUBSTITUTE function to change it back, so $D$1 contains `=SUBSTITUTE(C1,"'=","=")`, then just copy out to Notepad and paste back into $E$1

The other way would be to 'show formulas' but that would show formulas for every cell, not just a selected range.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function is_formula(c As Range) As Boolean
  is_formula = Left(c.Formula, 1) = "="
End Function
```

Comment: Can you add s short explanation to tell us what is going on here? :)

Comment: Just stick it in a VBA module, although I realize now the OP didn't want VBA. But anyway, that's why I use.

Comment: That's not really an explanation